# Series with log and exponential $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^a}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How could this series be solved: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log n}{n^a}$$

I was thinking of comparing it with the convergent series $\frac1{n^b}$ where b>1 and using the comparison test but I get stuck. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the series

$$\sum \frac{\log n}{n^a}$$

- for $a\le 0$ diverges since $a_n\to +\infty$
- for $0< a\le 1$ diverges by comparison with $$\sum \frac1{n^a}$$
- for $a> 1$ converges by comparison with $$\sum \frac1{n^{\frac{a+1}2}}$$